# d3.js Zooming in ie10 in metro view on windows 8 tablet

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have zoom activated on my graph and mouse events work fine and touch events work on the iPad.

However, trying them on IE 10 it does not work. Is this because IE10 does not support touch events and instead supports pointer events?

Is there a way to get this working or do I just need to hook up hammer.js to make life easier and work for all touch events on ie10 and iPad?

Cheers
Mark